# Reverting "Do you want to find PC's, devices and content"

Tags: networking, printing, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-terminal-services

We are having some problems with printers automatically being added on a 2012R2 RDS host, and suspect the following dialog (where we pressed Yes) to be the issue..

How can this setting be reverted?

It is a virtual server in a domain network (and is joined to the domain)

[image: Dialog box]

Comment: [Try this... the CLI part, obviously](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/7682-how-to-change-a-network-from-public-to-private-in-windows-8-1.html)... it works for 8.1, so it *should* work for Server 2012 R2, though I can't test right now due to work-related BS.

Comment: @HopelessN00b did you forget to post something? :-)

Comment: No, it's a hyperlink.  The words "Try this... the CLI part, obviously" are a hyperlink to a blog.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - Ah, i noticed now.. Will something really bad happen if I changed the registry category from 2 to 0?

Comment: Well, worst that would happen is that it breaks your network interface (which you can always uninstall and have rediscovered).  So, no, nothing "really bad."  That said, when I get some time, I'm going diff the registry keys on interfaces which have a different selection on that stupid popup question, and see what effect Mr. Jensen's answer has on the interface registry keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Control Panel -> "Network and Sharing Center" and pick the "Change advanced sharing settings" link in the left pane.

Under "Domain" profiles, make sure Network Discovery is turned off:

[image]

Comment: Is that enough? It doesn't do anything else but that?