# How to avoid the prompt “Do you want to find PCs, devices, and content”?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012-r2

When a Windows Server (2012 or -R2) comes back from Stopped+Deallocated state in Azure, the “Do you want to find PCs, devices, and content on this network, and automatically connect to devices like printers and TVs?” question often appears:

[image]

The question appears again and again because Windows creates new network profiles, I guess due to Azure it feels to have new network adapters: after a few weeks of regular turn off/on cycles the (only one) network adapter listed is named "Ethernet 89" and the network profile is named "Network 19" - note the numbers.

Solutions I found so far to this problem suggest setting the public/private property of the network profile, which does not help as it is a *new* network profile every time.
[Others](https://serverfault.com/a/604107) suggest turning off network discovery in the Domain profiles, but I don't have that:

[image]

The above settings don't prevent Windows from displaying the question for every new network profiles.

I must avoid this prompt because it steals the focus from a GUI program that is about to be started and automated on this server.

How to disable this question about new networks?

Comment: Can you force Windows to always choose "Public" as the network type? I know at least on Windows 7 selecting Home/Office pops up with that prompt (and homegroup...ugh), but Public doesn't.

Comment: @Nathan I'm not sure I understand what do you mean. What is Home/Office, where is this setting?
AFAIK selecting between Public↔Private, or creating a Homegroup is only possible on a
particular network profile. The core of the problem here is that a new network profile
is created every time, so it doesn't matter what was set for a previous one.
To be specific: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards`
contains 89 subkeys (only 1 is used) and `...\NetworkList\Profiles` contains 19 subkeys
(only 1 is used).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution, try to create the registry key
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NewNetworkWindowOff

Reference
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252535(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Along with the link, will you include the steps for modifying the registry entry in the answer itself?

Comment: [There is a blog post](https://pbradz.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/windows-server-2012-r2-vms-and-the-network-location-wizard/)
about the difficulties with setting that registry key. (TL;DR: instead of regedit, use `reg add` from the console).
Unfortunately I cannot try this out on the server I mentioned in the question and confirm that this method really works, this is why I don't accept this answer, but +1

Answer (score 2):

I changed the following two services to Disabled:

- ltdsvc (Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper)
- NlaSvc (Network Location Awareness)

and the problem seems to be solved.
However, I'm not satisfied with this solution, there must be a less obtrusive way.

Comment: You're missing a character. ltdsvc needs to be lltdsvc.

Answer (score 0):

Open an elevated Command Prompt (CMD) and type :

```
    reg ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NewNetworkWindowOff /f
```

Comment: It is recommended to explain any command and code samples you include, so that the answer is clearer and more useful - could you do so please?